# Unicode text get's broken in half on a unicode character when inserting into Mysql table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't get this -> why when I record a string -> half of it get's stripped out?

SQL CODE:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_test_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE my_test_db;
CREATE TABLE my_test_table(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dt TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    ini_set("default_charset", 'utf-8');
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_test_db;port=3306;charset=utf8';
    $dbh = new Pdo($dsn, 'username', 'super-secret-pass');
    $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dt = '<dt>blah blah  blah2 blah2</dt>';
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO my_test_table(dt) VALUES(:dt)";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
    $sth->bindParam(":dt", $dt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
?>
```

WHAT'S RECORDED:

```
mysql> select * from my_test_table;
+----+----------------+
| id | dt             |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | <dt>blah blah  |
|  2 | <dt>blah blah  |
|  3 | <dt>blah blah  |
|  4 | <dt>blah blah  |
+----+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

^  why in the world everything after  get's stripped -> I'm loosing my mind already...

**RESOLVED**

Holy crap - it's amazing.
biberu @ freenode ##php immensely helped me with this issue:
Turns out mysql utf8 charset doesn't support 4 byte unicode and one MUST use utf8m4b charset for full unicode support. And mysql would just **SILENTLY TRUNCATE** the string after 4byte character.

Use this for the win:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_test_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE my_test_db;
CREATE TABLE my_test_table(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dt TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: [Collation on mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)? just a guess, but the [default is latin1](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/138/Default+MySQL+character+set+and+collation#gs) and oftentimes needs to be changed.

Comment: You need to make sure you are using UTF-8 charset and collationson your DB tables/fields.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes - afaik it's all UTF-8. I've added sql code -> plz. try yourself.

Comment: @hd1 it's utf8_general_ci collation afaik.

Comment: Are you sure `TEXT` is the right data type for your use case? I'm pretty sure `VARCHAR(size)` better fits your requirements...

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: what char is ```` ? and what gives dump of `$dt` ?

Comment: ZombieHunter,moskito I've figured it out (biberu @ freenode ##php told me about it) - > turns out mysql utf8 charset doesn't support 4 byte unicode and one MUST use utf8m4b charset for full unicode support. And mysql would just truncate the string after 4byte character.